# Related Rates: Find $\frac{dr}{dt}$ given that $e^{xy}$...

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have been trying to work this question out for a couple of days now and don't understand it.
I know $r=e^{2×1/3}$ but can't work out how to do the derivatives with respect to $t$.

> Suppose $\frac{dx}{dt}=4,\frac{dy}{dt}=8$. Find $\frac{dr}{dt}$ given that $r=e^{xy}$ when $x=6y=2$ exactly.

Comment: I solved it. The formatting of the page was wrong so instead of x=6y=2, it should have read x=6, y=2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** By the chain rule,
$$ \frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} (e^{xy}) = e^{xy}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(xy) = e^{xy}\left( \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} y + x\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt} \right). $$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that$${dr\over dt}={dr\over dx}{dx\over dt}+{dr\over dy}{dy\over dt}=4yr+8xr=e^{2\over 3}(16+{4\over 3})$$

Comment: the answer provided is 56e^12, which I don't see how
@Mostafa

Comment: Well I don't see it either. Are you sure from the answer?